# Any substitute for itcl::find in native OO?

Tags: tcl, itcl

Is there any substitute for itc::find in native OO.

I need to delete all classes in a particular namespace
My code runs like:

```
foreach class [::itcl::find classes ::MYNAMESPACE::*] {catch {::itcl::delete class $class}}
```

How do I do this in native OO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is to make all your classes subclass a dummy class that doesn't need to do anything, say `MYNAMESPACE::DeletionToken`. Then, just delete that dummy class with `MYNAMESPACE::DeletionToken destroy`; all the subclasses and instances will then be automatically slaughtered neatly. This also works with mixins and metaclasses. Also remember that TclOO supports multiple inheritance so none of this needs to disturb your existing code much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - following does it:

```
 foreach class [info class instances oo::class ::MYNAMESPACE::*] {
      catch {$class destroy}
 }
```

Comment: That'll go wrong with metaclasses in the mix. Most people don't use them, but they do exist.

Comment: Thanks Donal, 
I have not worked with the metaclasses - but won't the catch prevent any error that results while destroying metaclasses. This would also mean that metaclasses won't be deleted but if one is not using metaclasses still should that be a problem?